# Bitwise and in PHP

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I am very new face to PHP. I read that `dechex(255)` will give the corresponding hex value `ff` in PHP.

I need the hex value of `-105`. I tried `dechex(-105)` and got the result as `ffffff97`. But I just only want `97` to do some kind of stuffs.

In Java I know that a bit wise operation with `0xff` gave us the result `97` that is `(byte)-105 & (byte)0xff = 0x97`.

Please to find the solution in PHP just like I've done in Java.

Comment: That value is probably correct: bear in mind that `-1` is all bits set (all `f`s). These values are regarded as negative because the left-most bit is set. You'll find you get the same result in Java too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in php like this:

```
var_dump(dechex(-105 & 255))
```

to make it out of the final byte (example output below)

```
string(2) "97"
```

Answer (score 1):

dechex() gives you a hexadecimal value for a decimal value between 0 and 2*PHP_INT_MAX+1 (unsigned int).

Anything below 0 or above 2*PHP_INT_MAX+1, will loop.

**-105 is NOT 0xffffff97 , and it is not 0x97**

0xffffff97 is 4294967191.
and 0x97 is 151.

If you want the hexadecimal representation of the negative number turned into a positive number, use the function `abs()`.

```
$abs = abs(-105); // $abs becomes +105
$hex = dechex($abs); // $hex becomes 69
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you want a binary negative value (ffffff97) or a signed value

```
// for a signed value
$i = -105;
if($i < 0)
     echo '-'.dechex(abs($i));
else echo dechex($i);
```

If you want to remove front "f"

```
echo preg_replace('#^f+#', '', dechex($i));
```

Comment: That `if` statement doesn't do a lot on its own. If you meant for that to affect the following statement, remove the `;` -- and you should use braces anyway, to remove the ambiguity.